# load jstree from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm trying to use jstree to provide a tree. The nodes of the tree should be extracted from a javascript array element. For example, my array is Library={Milk,Bread,Cheese,...}
So I want parent nodes to be Milk, Bread, Cheese, ...
Here is part of the code that I tried, I want to initialize the jstee_data based on the array. Here I just intialize that manullay. but can I do that in a loop or some thing? Because if say the array has 20 elements it is hard to code that manullay!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var lib_info = new Array();
    lib_info[0]= new library_Object("Milk");
    lib_info[1]= new library_Object("Bread");
    lib_info[2]= new library_Object("Cheese");
    $("#someButton").click(function() {
        $("#treeContainer").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "data": [
                    { "data": lib_info[0].libData, "children": ["Child 1", "A Child 2"] }, { "data": lib_info[1].libData, "children": ["Child 1", "A Child 2"] }, { "data": "Last node" },                ]
            },
            "plugins": ["ui", "json_data", "themes"]
        });
    });

});
function library_Object(lib_data) {
    this.libData = lib_data;
}
</script>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide working jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yZQJH/118/

Comment: OK, so what doesn't work? How do you want to store children of a node? Why do you want to do the processing in the browser and not on a server side?

Comment: So in this script I just add parent node from array elements manually. But I want to add them in a loop. some thing like for (i=0;i<lib_info.length; i++) { { "data": lib_info[i].libData, "children": ["Child 1", "A Child 2"] }, } but I don't know how to do that!!! I'm new to java script, can you point me to some material about to how should I do this in server side?! thanks for your help.

Comment: You are on the right track since you are using the json_data plugin.  Convert your data to the valid json format that the tree expects(you can do this on the server side if you want to).  Store the data in a javascript variable as part of the script you pass to the client, and then just assign it to the data parameter of json_data plugin.

Comment: @Eli: you really need to think how you want to store/generat the data. Is every node going to have the same children? Is every node going to have children? More importantly how do you want to store such information? Then we can talk how to code it but now we need to know where the data (structure) comes from and how do you want to generate it. I still do not understand why the data manipulation needs to be done on the client.